# Derived subgroup of rational points vs. rational points of derived subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected split reductive group over a field $k$. In general, we have an inclusion
$$
f: [G(k), G(k)] \rightarrow [G,G](k).
$$
If $k$ is not algebraically closed, $f$ is not necessarily an equality (e.g. $\mathrm{PGL}_n$ over a finite field).

I have two closely related questions:

Question 1: What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $G$ so that $f$ is an equality regardless of the ground field?

For instance, if $G$ has simply connected derived subgroup, then $f$ is an equality for any field, cf. discussions of this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133072/on-the-f-rational-points-of-the-derived-group-of-a-connected-reductive-algebra). But I'm not sure if this condition is necessary.

Question 2: Suppose $k$ is a finite field. What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $G$ so that $f$ is an equality?

Comment: When $k$ is a finite field and $G$ is semisimple, then $f$ is an equality exactly when the center $Z_{\tilde G}$ of the universal cover $\tilde G$ of $G$ has no nontrivial $k$-points, i.e., $Z_{\tilde G}(k)=1$.

Comment: Hi Kenta, what is the argument for this?

Comment: By the discussion in the linked post, $f$ being an equality is equivalent to $\tilde G(k)\to G(k)$ being surjective. But $\tilde G(k)$ and $G(k)$ have the same size, by looking at the long exact sequence attached to $1\to Z_{\tilde G}\to \tilde G\to G\to 1$. Thus we need $\tilde G(k)\to G(k)$ to be injective, which is equivalent to $Z_{\tilde G}(k)=1$.